# How can I add keys to a PHP array, if I need those keys to have a value (passed from a DB) at the same time?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

The problem is here: I'm trying to write a code which would make a dynamic PHP array. I have an empty array, to which need to add keys with their values, values being passed by a do-while loop from the MySQL server.
The following php code:

```
$result=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT products_id,voted,rating FROM      table_products $sorting LIMIT 6");
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {

$a = array();
do {

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $obj=$row['products_id'];
    $rating=$row['rating'];
    $voted=$row['voted'];



    array_push($a,array('obj'.$obj => array('rating' =>
        $rating, 'voted' => $voted)));

} while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)
);}

$json = json_encode($a);
echo $json;
```

...gives me this json string:

```
[{"obj1":{"rating":"25","voted":"5"}},{"obj3":{"rating":"36","voted":"10"}},{"obj5":{"rating":"6","voted":"4"}}]
```

...but I need this:

```
["obj1":{"rating":"25","voted":"5"},"obj3":{"rating":"36","voted":"10"},"obj5":{"rating":"6","voted":"4"}]
```

So how can I push this:

```
'obj'.$obj => array('rating' => $rating, 'voted' => $voted)
```

whithout putting it in a separate array, like I did in my code? I just don't know a right way to implement this.

Comment: how about json_decode();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
array_push($a,array('obj'.$obj => array('rating' => $rating, 'voted' => $voted)));
```

To

```
$a['obj'.$obj] = array('rating' =>  $rating, 'voted' => $voted);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of array_push

```
$a = array_merge($a, array(
    'obj'.$obj => array(
        'rating' => $rating,
        'voted' => $voted
    )
));
```